# @Inject not working on Quarkus + Vertx + Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, vert.x, quarkus

I am trying to write a simple reactive application using Quarkus and Kotlin with just one endpoint and using Vertx. But this simple piece of code does not work:

```
package com.acme

import io.quarkus.vertx.web.Route
import io.vertx.core.Vertx
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpMethod
import io.vertx.ext.web.RoutingContext
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped
import javax.inject.Inject

@ApplicationScoped
open class Routing {

    @Inject
    lateinit var vertx: Vertx

    @Route(path = "/hello", methods = [HttpMethod.GET])
    fun handle(rc: RoutingContext) {
        println(vertx)
        rc.response().end("hello")
    }
}
```

I get this exception:

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property vertx has not been initialized
        at com.acme.Routing.handle(Routing.kt:18)
```

I have read Quarkus documentation about Kotlin (it's still a preview technology) and says something about using '@field: xxx' but I have tried a lot of things and none worked. It would be greatly appreciated if someone knows the answer.

I have tried the same in Java and works perfectly. @Inject Vertx or @Inject EventBus but in Kotlin seems impossible

Answer (score 1):

I took your example class and it's working fine: https://github.com/dankito/QuarkusKotlinInjetStackoverflowQuestion.

(Simply execute `./gradlew quarkusDev` in project folder.)

Did you setup your project with the Quarkus project creator https://code.quarkus.io/?

Check "Eclipse Vert.x", "Eclipse Vert.x - Web" and "Kotlin" (add the bottom) there.

You then should have the following dependencies on your class path (Gradle notation):
- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8
- io.quarkus:quarkus-kotlin
- io.quarkus:quarkus-vertx
- io.quarkus:quarkus-vertx-web

Comment: Yes, yours it's working OK. The only difference I see is that I'm using Maven. Here you can see: https://github.com/petermota/reactive-file-explorer. And yes I generated it with Quarkus generator so I didn't change anything in pom.xml

Comment: No. The problem was solved chaging to Gradle as you did in Github. Very strange

Answer (score 1):

According to https://quarkus.io/guides/kotlin#cdi-inject-with-kotlin one should add `@field: Default` "to handle the lack of a @Target on the Kotlin reflection annotation definition":

```
    @Inject
    @field: Default
    lateinit var vertx: Vertx
```